# Summing first k elements of Python list?

Tags: python, list, sum

How can I sum the first *k* items in a given list?

For example:

```
myList = [1,2,5]
```

How can I use *k* to return 1 for *k* = 1, 3 for *k* = 2 and 8 for *k* = 3?

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're happy to help when you encounter a specific problem.

Comment: OK, I see and accept it. I first looked for the answer in the tutorial in my language and (my fault) I didn't find immediately an answer. So, I thought that it would have been interesting to ask for a _oneliner_ to accomplish the task, ignoring that the simplest way to do that is already a oneliner. In conclusion, I can understand that sometimes being newbie is considered laziness or, even worse, stupidity but @Matt be patient: sometimes already existing answers are not sufficiently general, or simply asked to be understood by a newbie and this causes them to post duplicates (for experts). Bye

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two options, both using `sum()`:

- Use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to efficiently extract those elements:

  ```
  from itertools import islice
  sum(islice(somelist, k))
  ```
- Slice the list to get a copy with just those first elements:

  ```
  sum(somelist[:k])
  ```

`islice()` is more memory efficient and can compete with slicing:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> somelist = list(range(10000))
>>> k = 1
>>> timeit.timeit('sum(somelist[:k])', 'from __main__ import somelist, k')
0.23189388398895971
>>> timeit.timeit('sum(islice(somelist, k))', 'from __main__ import somelist, k; from itertools import islice')
0.2557754369918257
>>> k = len(somelist) // 2
>>> timeit.timeit('sum(somelist[:k])', 'from __main__ import somelist, k')
51.454719836998265
>>> timeit.timeit('sum(islice(somelist, k))', 'from __main__ import somelist, k; from itertools import islice')
53.374267254024744
```

Even for a large `k`, the `islice()` version is within the same ballpark as slicing, but we didn't have to create another list object with `k` references first.

Comment: Thank you very much @Martijn. A little curiosity: how big must be a list to be _big_ enough and justify the use of itertools (order of magnitude, I mean)?

Comment: @Orso: When I tested this, it turned out `islice()` is always going to beat a direct slice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "This beats out `sum(somelist[:k])` for any size" - This statement seems incorrect? I am unable to reproduce these timings on IPython3. Furthermore, `islice` is much slower for larger values of `k`. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: uhm, no, indeed, the data posted here indeed doesn't seem to support that assertion. I'll revisit.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: updated. Not sure where I even got the timings from, for the given input size those were well off the mark.

Comment: It looks alright now, thank you. Although, admittedly, the timing differences between the two are more pronounced on my machine - 68us vs 82us for the large sample. Even more interesting - If I increase the input size to `1000000` elements to sum to half, `islice` starts winning - I would assume this difference is due to the overhead of memory allocation the `[:k]` slicer creates.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: exactly, larger lists take more time to copy.